# Slider Pro Slide Count

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel

Using [slider-pro](https://belle-fleur-dev02.myshopify.com/blogs/bfmagazine), I am having trouble getting slide count for the number of slides inside the carousel. I have looked at [this solution](http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/), but am having no luck. My code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
 $('.slider-pro').sliderPro();
});

 var slider = $( this ).data( 'sliderPro' );

 $(this).append('<div class="counter"><span class="active">'+ (parseInt(slider.getSelectedSlide()) + 1) +'</span>/'+slider.getTotalSlides()+'</div>');
 slider.on( 'gotoSlide', function( event ) {
 $(this).find('.counter .active').text(event.index + 1);
 });
```

But I get a console error:

`TypeError: slider is undefined, can't access property "getSelectedSlide" of it`

I am not much of a jquery guy, so I'm not sure why it is giving me this error when in fact the property `getSelectedSlide` is defined in the [jquery.sliderPro.js](https://github.com/bqworks/slider-pro/blob/master/dist/js/jquery.sliderPro.js) file. Perhaps I'm not calling it correctly or need to bind the property to a class or id. I'm not sure. I've tried both, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks so much!

---

Unfortunately, I'm using the class selector to initialize multiple sliders on the same page with the same parameters. I don't want to use id because I will have to create a unique id for every slider instance, which I don't want and will become unmanageable. I also cannot dynamically generate an id for each slider. An example page is here:
[BFMagazine](https://belle-fleur-dev02.myshopify.com/blogs/bfmagazine)

Right now, I have to hardcode the slider number/total into every slide, which isn't ideal.

The relevant [Slider-Pro](http://bqworks.com/slider-pro/) js used is:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.slider-pro').sliderPro({
    width: '100%',
    arrows: true,
    fadeArrows: false,
    buttons: false,
    fade: true,
    fadeDuration: 200,
    thumbnailPosition: 'bottom',
    thumbnailWidth: 75,
    thumbnailHeight: 75,
    autoplay: false,
    fullScreen: false,
    breakpoints: {
      480: {
        thumbnailWidth: 40,
        thumbnailHeight: 40
      }
    }
  });

  $.each('.slider-pro', function() {

      var slider = $('.slider-pro').data('sliderPro');

      $('.slider-pro').append('<div class="counter"><span class="active">' + (parseInt(slider.getSelectedSlide()) + 1) +
    '</span>/' + slider.getTotalSlides() + '</div>');

      slider.on('gotoSlide', function(event) {
      $('.slider-pro').find('.counter .active').text(event.index + 1);
      });

    });

});
```

I'm getting a console error:

```
TypeError: cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in '.slider-pro'
```

I am using `jquery-2.1.4.min.js`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple issue actually the code you have found is missing some other details regarding how it's being used; that code need to be used inside an object or event handler context so `this` will refer to the object but in your case you are trying to use it outside so there is no context for `this` therefore we can't use it as such.

Anyway as you have told you are new to jquery that's fine; what you need to do is instead of using `this` use the css selector directly if you are "outside", so you have

```
 var slider = $('.slider-pro').data( 'sliderPro' );
 // here this is not ok as it is "outside"

 $('.slider-pro').append('<div class="counter"><span class="active">'+ (parseInt(slider.getSelectedSlide()) + 1) 
 +'</span>/'+slider.getTotalSlides()+'</div>');

 slider.on('gotoSlide', function( event ) {
   $(this).find('.counter .active').text(event.index + 1);
   // here this is ok as it is "inside"
 });
```

**Update**:

You were almost there but instead of using [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) each you were needed to use [this](https://api.jquery.com/each/) each, the difference between the two is that the second one specially used for Dom nodes and you can use `this` magic inside to refer to each item without actually giving them any explicit property like ids

```
  $('.slider-pro').each(function(index, element) {

      //using $(element) instead of $(this) should work too

      $(this).sliderPro({
         //..options
      });              

      var slider = $(this).data('sliderPro');

      $(this).append('<div class="counter"><span class="active">' + (parseInt(slider.getSelectedSlide()) + 1) +
    '</span>/' + slider.getTotalSlides() + '</div>');

      slider.on('gotoSlide', function(event) {
        $(this).find('.counter .active').text(event.index + 1);
        // finds only the .counter and .active inside the current slider divsnot touching .counter and .active of other slider divs
      });


    });
```

A brief explanation would be, the `$(selector).each(..)` loops over all the Dom nodes that match the selector and gives you a context `this` that will always refer to the current item of the iteration but only within the scope of each function.For instance if matched items are a set of `<div>`s then you can refer to each `<div>` individually

Comment: Worked like a charm once I put it inside the event handler. Thanks so much!

Comment: The only problem with this now is that I have multiple sliders functioning on the same page but it will only count the number of slides for the first instance of the slider. Is there any way to calculate the slides for each slider independently?

Comment: Yes because we use class selector, can you post the relevant code html and javascript?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Please see additional info to the original question above.